# How to use SplitPane.Divider class using Splitpane in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

Can anyone tell me how to use SplitPane.Divider class using Splitpane in javafx and Also how to put two - two buttons in both the pane?
For Example:

```
import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;    
import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane.Divider;    

public class Demo{    
SplitPane pane = new SplitPane();      
pane.SplitPane.Divider();         // I cant use like that   
}
```

is there any other way to use SplitPane.Divider class

Comment: Sorry you dont understand my question ,
 I want to use single divider using static nested Divider class in the SplitPane and also methods of SplitPane class

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SplitPane.html) is your friend, as well as [code examples](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/SplitPane.htm). But from the looks of your code you [better start here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm).